# Monitoring Redis with fluentd

Tags: docker, redis, fluentd

I am using fluentd as my log concentrator for all my docker containers.

I would like to monitor my redis instance with the data from the info command (https://redis.io/commands/info)
All the articles I can find uses redis as a log storage for other services.
But I want to monitor the redis instance itself.

But I can not find a way to output the statistics to the docker logging system, except implementing my own solution. Anyone have a working setup to get statistics from redis into docker/fluentd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [built-in exec input plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_exec) with a small script to parse the result of redis info command?

Comment: You are so right, sometimes the most obvious solution eludes me. Thanks!

Comment: @FrederikBanke I know it's been asked a while ago, but did it work?